# POSTGRES ORDER BY random() with ROW_NUMBER not working as expected

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

```
let data = await Category.findAll({
  where: { list_category_id: body.category_id },
  attributes: {
    include: [
      [
        sequelize.literal(`COALESCE (
          CASE WHEN youtube_id_id IS NOT NULL THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY random(), youtube_id_id) END,
          CASE WHEN instagram_id_id IS NOT NULL THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY random(), instagram_id_id) END )`),
        "row_num",
      ],
    ],
  },
  order: [sequelize.literal("row_num")],
});
```

In a row only one would have a value either youtube_id_id or instagram_id_id, I came up with this so that I can get rows with values for both youtube_id_id and instagram_id_id column every time, but this only works without the random() in ORDER BY. I want to get random results each time I run this and at the same time ensure rows with both values are present. How can I make this work?

EDIT:

Category Table:

```
export const Category = sequelize.define(
  "category",
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: sequelize.literal("gen_random_uuid()"),
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    score: {
      type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      defaultValue: sequelize.literal("NOW()"),
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      defaultValue: sequelize.literal("NOW()"),
    },
  },
  {
    underscored: true,
    tableName: "Category",
  }
);
```

`youtube_id_id` and `instagram_id_id`, are foreign keys.

Sample Data:

| id | youtube_id_id | instagram_id_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| uuid |  | uuid |
| uuid | uuid |  |
| uuid | uuid |  |
| uuid |  | uuid |

Expected Output is a bit tricky to describe, I want data for each foreign key, say I limit the data to only 2, so I should always get rows that has values for both keys.

Basically what I think I want it, that when ROW_NUMBER() numbering starts from 1 instead of the first row it assigns it a random row and keep on going. This should get me results at random, is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Would you give us your table schema, some sample data, and your expected output?

Comment: @Schwern I have what I can, I hope its is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, just had to partition by column and group by random.

```
COALESCE (CASE WHEN youtube_id_id IS NOT NULL THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY youtube_id_id IS NOT NULL ORDER BY random()) END,
          CASE WHEN instagram_id_id IS NOT NULL THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY youtube_id_id IS NOT NULL ORDER BY random()) END)
```

Comment: Note that this will *always* alternate between rows with youtube and instagram IDs. If you ask for 10 rows, you'll get 5 with youtube and 5 with instagram IDs. [Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/-G3sLt20).

Comment: @Schwern yes that is what I need if there are only 3 insta ids then I would get a 7 - 3, it ensures I get max 10 always.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get random results each time I run this and at the same time ensure rows with both values are present.

You can make two queries and `union` them.

```
(
select *
from your_table
where youtube_id is null
  and instagram_id is not null
order by random()
limit 1
)

union

(
select *
from your_table
where youtube_id is not null 
  and instagram_id is null
order by random()
limit 1
)
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/tnrU9a0q).

Sequelize doesn't directly support `union`, but you can simulate it by [combining two queries with a `Promise.all`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66551646/14660).

Comment: yes a union would work but sequelize doesn't support union operation, I would have to run it as a raw query, which might not be safe.

Comment: @Arsh [You can simulate it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66551646/14660).

Comment: Yes I have tried this, but I am working with multiple tables and a lot of joins, so the query gets really large when dividing into parts, seems easy to just do it in one.

Comment: @Arsh In cases where you have lots of columns you want to treat the same, this may indicate a table redesign is needed. An intermediate ServiceAccount table might help which you then join against. You could ask another question about how to handle foreign keys which are similar but slightly different.